# Banding in saved image from Camera on Android

Tags: android, image, camera

So I've implemented my own version of a camera app on Android. Everything seems to work well except I have a user with a MyTouch 4G and his images are turning out striped and messed up:

[image: Image he gets from saving]

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Has anyone seen this before?

Also: Users with other devices are having their pictures come out just fine.

Edit: I've now been able to see this happen on the device. When taking the picture about half the screen flashes green. Then the picture comes out as seen above. I've tried saving the byte[] many different ways. It seems the data I'm getting really is corrupt. I'm using the jpeg onPictureTaken callback and just saving off that byte[]. And again. I've ONLY been able to see this on a few MyTouch 4G devices. I really am at a loss here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

i say you are copying data and you might be missing some pixels on the end of each row. maybe you have the width wrong in your calcs?

Comment: or maybe the MyTouch 4G is reporting the width incorrectly ... maybe you can fix the width?

Comment: I don't deal with the width. I just get the data from the onPictureTaken callback of the camera. I just realized though I was saving the pictures as .png (which works fine on my phone) but the normal camera app saves them as .jpg. I've sent the new version to my beta testers. If this fixes the problem I'll be sure to post my resolution!

Comment: definitely looks like an incorrect width problem to me .. are you setting the cameraParameters at all? also sometime in low memory conditions the image is subsampled which leads to width changes.

Comment: @siliconeagle Yeah I am setting the camera parameters. I have a method that looks at the supported sizes and sets the size accordingly. And like I said, it works good on the 4 other phones i've tried it on. Just not on a MyTouch 4G.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not saying it's your bug - might be a phone bug too ;) (I have seem loads of weird stuff happen on particular phones)

Comment: @siliconeagle And I'm pretty sure it's not a low memory condition. The MyTouch 4G has 768 MB of RAM. And I even had my friend download an app up and his VM size to 46MB and it didn't help. I might just have to not support the MT4G. Such a shame! Yeah it can get hard to support all phones when you need specific hardware things like cameras. Thanks for your suggestions though :)

Comment: just for posterity i am never mentioned memory - i mention pixelWidth - memory is a red herring here.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing a very similar issue using the HTC Thunderbolt. I saved the image data byte[] from PictureCallback.onPictureTaken() directly to the SD card. When I viewed the image on the SD card, it showed the same banding effect.

I then realized I was setting the previewSize in the camera parameters. I was using this code:

```
// Ensure that the camera resolution is a multiple of 8, as the screen may not be.
// TODO: A better solution would be to request the supported preview resolutions
// and pick the best match, but this parameter is not standardized in Cupcake.
Point cameraResolution = new Point();
cameraResolution.x = ( screenResolution.x >> 3 ) << 3;
cameraResolution.y = ( screenResolution.y >> 3 ) << 3;
parameters.setPreviewSize( cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y );
```

When I removed this code and did not set the preview size at all, my images were no longer banded.

Comment: I'll look into this. Basically I had given up and just said that the MyTouch 4G was unsupported with my application. Haha. And I was setting my preview sized based on the closest supported size, like your comments above your code says. I don't really see how I could go about not setting the preview size, I'm pretty sure that would cause crashes on a lot of phones, yeah?